# Output a fake TV Channel?

Tags: video, output, vlc

I recently went on a Disney cruise with my family and the TV had different channels that had films on a loop different channels were different categories.

My wife and I REALLY liked this and wanted to know if it was possible to do at home.

My ideal scenario would be we get a Pi and plug it in, which outputs some 'fake channels' to the TV which can be picked up.

The Pi channels are picked up from video files found on the network.

Am I missing something that does this (I've had a Google) or is what I'm thinking completely ridiculous?

Comment: I'm sure you could write some sort of Python script to randomly play videos from a set folder. And also add in some key commands to to select which folder the videos are played from. Which would effectively give you different channels. However, this is really too broad for the scope of the site. I don't think coding this would be hard. I suggest you start looking at tutorials on how to create code to play videos stored in set locations and go from there.

Comment: No need to program anything. I'd install kodi and try to the suggestion from [this forum](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=155071&page=2).